# Firebase saving a unique interger id to child

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following json, which I save to firebase using $push.

```
{"eventId" : x, eventName : "nameofevent", speakers: [101, 102]}
```

How do I store a unique integer (int32) in eventId?

I would use the key produced by the reference but it has to be an integer.

Comment: You can't use timestamp in miliseconds?

Comment: @AmiHollander I've been using timestamp, but it produces a 13 digit integer which is too long. I need it to be int32 specifically(10 digits).. :/ An open source app I'm building consumes rest api, which I produce and it requires the id to be of size int32.

Comment: You can always store a `unique id` on the database and read it when push data. But I think it's not the best solution.

Comment: @AmiHollander I would but it's not secure.

Comment: To generate a 10 digit integer, there are probably some solutions out there. Then to guarantee its uniqueness, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970681/enforcing-unique-usernames-with-firebase-simplelogin

Comment: `ID`s are usually simply consecutive numbers, so `ID = lastID + 1`, where `lastID` is the largest ID yet.