# Firebase Fan-out update validation in Bolt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Lets assume we have a data structure similar to the one below, and using fan-out update we want to convert an invitation to a user.

- root

  - users

    - KC88nKzEqsx6AlPjrvp

      - email : test1@yahoo.com
      - uid: 19570b6c-afd0-xxxx-xxxx-650be04c5767
    - KCAW6T_au2ROnJcaf85

      - email : test2@yahoo.com
      - uid: 22570b6c-afd0-xxxx-xxxx-650be04c5767
  - invitations

    - KCZndfnKzEqrtr6AlPjrvp

      - email : test3@yahoo.com
    - BYYAW6T_au2Rffeaf85

      - email : test4@yahoo.com

Update code:

```
var update = {}
update[‘invitations/KCZndfnKzEqrtr6AlPjrvp’] = null
update[‘users/DDd83sx6AlPjrvp’] = {email:test3@yahoo.com, uid: 773492-afd0-344-4535-650be04c5767}

ref.update(update);
```

How can i write validate rules in Bolt, that will check if:

1. Invitation for such email existed.
2. The newly created user email is equal to email on invitation
3. User uid is his actual id from auth object.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Some of these should not be too difficult if you follow along with the Bolt documentation and read recent questions about [firebase-bolt] and [firebase-security].

Comment: @frank thank's for your interest. I'm aware of documentation in [link](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/language.md) and on firebase website. Yet i have a problem writing validation rules that mention 3 nodes that are not siblings, and path leading to them is dynamic (i.e KC88nKzEqsx6AlPjrvp array key).

Comment: Ensuring unique properties will typically require that you add a dedicated node for the purpose. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase