# Unique usernames in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to implement Chris’ answer here: [Can I make Firebase use a username login process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543872/can-i-make-firebase-use-a-username-login-process) for the Facebook login but I can’t seem to get my head around it.

So far I’ve tried to set conditions on the textField but as Firebase observer works asynchronously, the conditions to check if the username exists in the database won’t work.

```
let usernameString = usernameTextField.text
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {

        let usernamesDictionary = post["usernames"] as! NSDictionary
        for (key, _) in usernamesDictionary {
            if key as? String == usernameString {
                print("username not available: \(key)")
            }
            else if usernameString == "" {
               print("Uh oh! Looks like you haven't set a username yet.")
            }
            else if key as? String != usernameString {
                print("username available: \(key)")
                print("All set to go!")

                let setValue: NSDictionary = [usernameString!: uid]
                post["usernames"] = setValue
                currentData.value = post  
            }
        }
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
    }
    return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
}
```

Then I tried creating /usernames/ node in the database and set up rules as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "usernames": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "newData.val() === auth.uid && !data.exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

Now that won’t let me set any username to the database. I get confused in creating rules but my whole point is that I need a sign up flow with the username data that’s unique for each user in the database.

Comment: Why are you trying to make the usernames unique? Firebase Auth has built in support for tons of providers, including email/password. And it will generate a unique UID for all accounts created.

Comment: @FibreChips yes but those are unique IDs generated automatically and not usernames the users can set by their choice.

Comment: What doesn't work about your current approach? The transaction block should fire (potentially multiple times), but (combined with security rules) should eventually allow you to securely claim a user-name.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it doesn’t let me set a username due to security rules now. The transaction block is working fine but I have an issue with the security rules.

Comment: Are you really running a transaction on your *entire* database? How about running it on the only level you care about: `ref.child("usernames").child(usernameString)`? If you run a transaction on that and `currentData` exists, abort the transaction (since the username is already claimed). If `currentData` doesn't exist, return your own auth.uid as the new value for the node.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found something that helped me for now, without making a change in the Firebase rules. But your recommendation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I can't see why the username should ever have to be unique. Hardly any other program has that requirement.

Comment: It often comes from chat programs where you can @-mention other users by name. Many developers want to implement that globally, hence: unique user namers. Better solutions implement a locally unique friendly username. For example: display names (e.g. "Frank van Puffelen" or "FibreChips") in Stack Overflow don't have to be unique. But somehow SO knows to ping me when you @FrankvanPuffelen, because it is unique within the context of this question. Although that @-mention becomes a dangling reference if I change my display name.

Answer (score 0):

While trying every answer I found in related posts, what worked for me the easy way i.e. without making Firebase rules play a part in it or creating a separate usernames node in the database was to not put an if/else condition inside the Firebase observer but instead to use the exists() method of FIRDataSnapshot.

Now here’s the trick, while I did try only the exists() method with a simple observer but that did not help me. What I did was first query usernames in order, then match the username with queryEqualToValue to filter the query:

```
refUsers.queryOrderedByChild("username").queryEqualToValue(usernameString).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value , withBlock: {
            snapshot in

            if !snapshot.exists() {
                if usernameString == "" {
                    self.signupErrorAlert("Uh oh!", message: "Looks like you haven't set a username yet.")
                }
                else {

                    // Update database with a unique username.

                }
            }
            else {
                self.signupErrorAlert("Uh oh!", message: "\(usernameString!) is not available. Try another username.")
            }

        }) { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }
```

This is the first time out of most of the answers here that worked for me. But for now, I don’t know if this would scale. Post your experiences and best practices. They’ll be appreciated.