# Store unique values in firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of users in Firebase database and every user has a nickname. I would like the nicknames to be unique. How can I do it that in Android ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970681/enforcing-unique-usernames-with-firebase-simplelogin), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260476/what-firebase-rule-will-prevent-duplicates-in-a-collection-based-on-other-fields), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506003/ensuring-unique-username-on-creating-a-new-user-in-firebase-swift) and probably many more from [this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+unique+username).

Comment: this link will help you https://androidheight.blogspot.in/2017/04/firebase-reatime-database.html