# Generate 6 digit unique number in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to generate 6 digit **unique** number in Firbase (unique must)
[image]

above attendeeCode should be unique on every new attendess entry

I am new in firebase and I have searched alot but could not find

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822372/4856245

Comment: That is unique, but not six characters

Comment: There is nothing specific to Firebase about generating a 6 digit number. But to ensure it must be unique, you'll want to look at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35243492) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37506003) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29970681).

Answer (score 3):

Create a six digit number that corresponds to the nth entry into `attendees`. And then keep track of that number elsewhere.

You can find in other questions that Firebase still does not support COUNT or LENGTH queries.

Create a path called `/meta-data` (arbitrary) and save the number of current attendees:

```
meta-data: {
    num_of_attendees: "000000" // parse this client side and send back padded string to keep 6 characters
}
```

Grab the value every time you add an attendee, increment it, and send it back. This keeps you from grabbing a list of all attendees and getting the length client-side.

A new option: [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

This is still in beta, but is having fair success. They provided and example of this functionality here:

[functions-sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count)

Comment: Thank you so much but currently I have already done like that, but although   posted question might be I get something new from someone :)

Comment: This won't work as expected because client can work offline too, the count change in server may not be realtime so it can be conflict