# Skip duplicates before saving to firebase cloud firestore with node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My project is a news feed application. I can successfully save data gotten from the API to firebase. However, I have duplicate news data saved on my database.

How can I prevent this.
See below my code:

```
// fetch news api
getData = (req, res) => {
return request(newsURL)
.then(news => (news.articles))
.then(infos => {infos.map((info) => {
    const newsDoc = {
        author: info.author,
        content: info.content,
        description: info.description,
        publishedAt: info.publishedAt,
        source: info.source.name,
        title: info.title,
        url: info.url,
        urlToImage: info.urlToImage,
        likeCount: 0,
        commentCount: 0
    }
    db.collection("feeds").add(newsDoc)
        .then((doc) => {
    const finalNews = newsDoc;
    finalNews.feedsId = doc.id;
    // res.json(finalNews)
})
.catch(err => console.error(err))
})})
};
```

I think a unique identifier of all the news data is the URL.

The question in this post - [Skip Duplicates in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005218/skip-duplicates-in-firebase-database/38019102#38019102), is related to mine, but I can seem to get it to work

Please how can I save unique news data without duplicates

See example of data from firebase database:

```
// original
{
    "feedsId": "Cjy5lW6g6StTVj1GjpQk",
    "author": "El Confidencial",
    "content": "Germán Loera, un conocido 'youtuber' en Mçexico de 25 años, ha sido condenado a 50 años de prisión por un delito de secuestro cometido en Chihuaha en 2018. Los secuestrados reclamaron la cantidad de dinero del rescate en bitcoin. Según ha informado la Fiscalí… [+1153 chars]",
    "description": "Germán Loera, de 25 años, ha sido condenado a 50 años de prisión junto a otros cinco hombres por secuestrar en 2018 a una abogada",
    "publishedAt": "2020-03-04T17:45:00Z",
    "title": "A prisión un 'youtuber' mexicano por un secuestro y pedir el rescate en bitcoins",
    "url": "https://www.elconfidencial.com/amp/mundo/2020-03-04/prision-youtube-mexico-secuestro-bitcoin_2482519/",
    "urlToImage": "https://www.ecestaticos.com/imagestatic/clipping/5c9/56e/5c956e35512404b3022b56dbe0b80c3b/a-prision-un-youtuber-mexicano-por-un-secuestro-y-pedir-el-rescate-en-bitcoins.jpg?mtime=1583343920",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "commentCount": 0
},

// duplicate
{
    "feedsId": "MqqFnixBwQmA0CoBzwr2",
    "author": "El Confidencial",
    "content": "Germán Loera, un conocido 'youtuber' en Mçexico de 25 años, ha sido condenado a 50 años de prisión por un delito de secuestro cometido en Chihuaha en 2018. Los secuestrados reclamaron la cantidad de dinero del rescate en bitcoin. Según ha informado la Fiscalí… [+1153 chars]",
    "description": "Germán Loera, de 25 años, ha sido condenado a 50 años de prisión junto a otros cinco hombres por secuestrar en 2018 a una abogada",
    "publishedAt": "2020-03-04T17:45:00Z",
    "title": "A prisión un 'youtuber' mexicano por un secuestro y pedir el rescate en bitcoins",
    "url": "https://www.elconfidencial.com/amp/mundo/2020-03-04/prision-youtube-mexico-secuestro-bitcoin_2482519/",
    "urlToImage": "https://www.ecestaticos.com/imagestatic/clipping/5c9/56e/5c956e35512404b3022b56dbe0b80c3b/a-prision-un-youtuber-mexicano-por-un-secuestro-y-pedir-el-rescate-en-bitcoins.jpg?mtime=1583343920",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "commentCount": 0
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is indeed a unique identifier that you could use.

In your code you are simply adding, try adding a check for the url like the example below:

```
let citiesRef = db.collection('feeds');
let query = citiesRef.where('url', '==', newsDoc.url).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log('No matching documents.');
            db.collection("feeds").add(newsDoc).then((doc) => {
                    const finalNews = newsDoc;
                    finalNews.feedsId = doc.id;
                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err))
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

Comment: hi, it did not work, it is still saving duplicate items

Comment: Are the URLs of these new duplicates unique? could you share a sample?

Comment: i have added the response from db

Comment: you are using node.js, correct? change the `doc.exists` for `doc.empty`, I will update the code from the answer so you can copy it

Comment: not working.. see error message: TypeError: db.collection(...).update is not a function

Comment: there was a typo in the code, missing a '(' on the `update().then(() =>`, fixed it on the code sample, try it out.

Comment: yeah, I corrected that earlier. error message persist. is it possible to just update the url if the url exist or what do you suggest the issue is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209086/discussion-between-ralemos-and-biggest-boy).