# firebase duplicate username and custom sign-in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My current firebase system allows me to signup with a new user using firebase createuser() taking an email and password, In the oncomplete method I also take the details used to sign up so the email and password along with some other variables I create such as username and DOB and save them to the firebase db with the following code:

```
// ...database code above
DatabaseReference users = database.getReference("users"); 
User user = new User(username, password,DOB,email); 
users.push().setValue(user);
```

1. I need to check now before saving to the database that the username is unique if it is not it asks for another username
2. I have also implemented a system where when the user logs in, it checks the String if it is an email or a username, if the user logs in with an email then it'll use firebase's system to login but if they use a username then it has to check the firebase database to see if the username exists and then checks if the password is correct

I have no idea how to do any of the above, any help is much appreciated thanks. I have used the stackoverflow search and realise there are posts with this question that has already been asked, I have tried a few of these solutions that didn't work because everyones database structure is different

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase and probably many other results in [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+unique+username)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me focus on the first problem as of now. **Unique Usernames.**

One of the key aspects of having a greater retrieval in Firebase is structuring data. How you structure determines how efficient is your application's functionality.

For unique usernames, I have suggest something like this in your Firebase Database.

[image]

In the above Database Structure, I have made a separate node for usernames that **not** available (true because ***some*** value is required). So that every-time when I have to check, I will not have to go through other details of the **USERS** node.

In your Application, you can use it this way to store Username.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference takenNames = database.getReference("TakenUserNames");

.
.
.
//On Successful Registeration
.
takenNames.child(username).setValue(true);
```

And while registering, you can retrieve that value like this:

```
public boolean doesNameExist(final String sUsername)
    {
theTakenNameRef = database.getReference("TakenUserName");
        theTakenNameRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(sUsername))
                {
                    isTaken = true;
                }
                else if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(sUsername))
                {
                    isTaken = false;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Connection Error. Please try again in some time.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return isTaken;
    }
.
.
.
.
.
.
//Calling it in method
String username = editText.getText().toString().trim().toUpperCase();
boolean exists = doesNameExist(username);
if(exists)
{
//Show Error
}
else
{
//Continue Registration
}
}
```

Hope this clears on how efficiently unique username can be checked.

And using this mechanism, you can put your logic for the second question as well.

Comment: I haven't read your entire answer yet, the way you described to do unique names - I had the same idea but thought it was bad because it feels like redundant data, if we had thousands of users this could take up a lot of space. or is this the simplest way to do it?

Comment: This is in-fact the simplest way to do it. Because here you are avoiding the retrieval of other user data just to get the username. For better understanding check this out: [Firebase: How to structure better data?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)

Comment: Okay, thank you I'll try implement this into my code and figure out 2) with the info provided also

Comment: Sure, let me know about it.

Comment: Great answer @TanishqSharma

Comment: It a huge appreciation coming from @Frank :)