# Firebase authentication rule checks email

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would like to only allow write permissions to authenticated users who have email addresses already in a user list.

My users list looks like this:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-KeZg-MuD-4TEOiW9i0_" : {
      "email" : "example@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using rules like this:

```
"users": {
  ".write" : "root.child('users/email').val() === auth.token.email"
}
"users": {
  ".write" : "root.child('users.email').val() === auth.token.email"
}
"users": {
  ".write" : "root.child('users.email').child(auth.token.email).exists()"
}
"users": {
  ".write" : "root.child('users').child(auth.token.email).exists()"
}
```

But to no avail. When I try to add a new user like this, I still get a permission denied error:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').push({email: 'example@gmail.com'})
```

My snippets above are using `example@gmail.com` instead of the actual google authenticated user's email address, but the actual user is present in my users db list.

Comment: Can you give a code example of something you tried that didn't do what you expected?

Comment: i'm adding users similar to the example i've added. I get a permission denied error afterwards.

Comment: I can't make much of the code you shared. Can you share your actual JSON (since your rules are checking against `root`) as text? You can get this by clicking Export JSON in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)

Comment: here's an export of my database: http://pastebin.com/1KE20xz7

Comment: I'd like allow only the user who has google authenticated with the email example@gmail.com to have write permissions

Comment: In the JSON you shared there is no path `/users/email`, so that rule will never be `true`. If you're looking to register unique email addresses, you should keep them as the key - not the value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149216/firebase-security-rules-to-check-unique-value-of-a-child-askfirebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique or my answer in this #AskFirebase video: https://youtu.be/66lDSYtyils?t=6m15s

Comment: i'm not trying to keep them unique. I want to limit permissions to users who have an email in my list of users.

Comment: That will lead to the same problem: you cannot in security rules search under a path for a specific *value*. You can check for the existence of a specific *key* though.

Comment: aha! now I understand and your previous answer does help! thank you! would you like to put it in an answer and i'll mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSON you shared there is no path `/users/email`. So this rule will never be `true`:

```
root.child('users/email').val() === auth.token.email
```

You cannot in security rules search under a path for a specific *value*. You can check for the existence of a specific *key* though. See [Firebase security rules to check unique value of a child #AskFirebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149216/firebase-security-rules-to-check-unique-value-of-a-child-askfirebase), [Firebase android : make username unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique) or my answer in this #AskFirebase video: https://youtu.be/66lDSYtyils?t=6m15s.