# Firebase: Check if any element has a specific property value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following JSON structure in my Firebase Database:

```
- users
    |
    +--- key: 123 
    |     |
    |     +-----name : Tom
    |     +-----email: tom@mymail.com
    |
    +--- key: 456 
          |
          +-----name : Peter
          +-----email: peter@othermail.com
```

Now I want to check if any user with the email `tom@mymail.com` exists or not.

I thought:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.getReference("users");
usersRef.orderByChild("email")
        .equalTo("tom@mymail.com")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //fires if exists
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {                            
    }
});
```

But this only fires if a user exists and not if it doesn't. How to do it properly?

Comment: See these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149216/firebase-security-rules-to-check-unique-value-of-a-child-askfirebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use exactly the code you provided. **It will fire no matter if it exists or not.** You only need to check if the data exists in the `onDataChange()` method:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.getReference("users");
usersRef.orderByChild("email")
        .equalTo("tom@mymail.com")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
           //exists!
        }
        else {
           //does not exist
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {                            
    }
});
```

I thought this does not work and I could swear I tried it (maybe with an earlier version of Firebase) but it works!

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of approaching this:

1. **Load the entire list of users and process it on the device** (Not recommended if you have a huge number of users, which you probably do). I will not post the code here because I'm affraid beginners will simply copy and paste it and write awful apps...
2. **Create a node containing the emails of users registered** (let's call it `userEmails`):

   `userEmails
   {
     "tom@mymail.com":true,
     "peter@othermail.com": true
   }`

Now, in order to check if the user exists or not:

```
usersRef.child("tom@mymail.com").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    //User exists
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //User doesn't exist
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
                        });
```

The downside of this is that you will have to insert data into both nodes when a new user is registered.

Comment: Another challenge of this method is that keys cannot have periods in them. If you store emails as keys, you will need to replace the period with a different character.

Comment: @JenPerson Idiomatically we use a `,` as the replacement for `.` in that case, since -conveniently- email addresses cannot contain `,`. :-)