# how can i delete from firebase realtime database before app close?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Problem is I can't remove data from firebase real-time database before close app

I have Button to delete data from database, When I write new data to database from app, I can't delete it directly , but when restart app I can delete the old data that I wrote it before close app

this link have code [how can i delete data from database before close app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947463/how-can-i-delete-data-from-database-before-close-app)

pls help me I have project must do it

thx in advance

Comment: Please do not post identical question twice . You can edit your previous question and it will get up in active queue.

Comment: [solution here for delete data from firebase when user close app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547779/delete-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-when-user-closes-app)

Comment: i don't know how to use onDestroy and onStop() and onReusem

Comment: if you know how do it pls tell me i need you