# Firebase Rules: How to validate duplicated with push id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Web SDK in my project. At the moment I am creating a simple mailing list sign up form. I am trying to check that no duplicate emails get signed up. At the moment, it is possible to do this as firebase creates a message id one level up from the data being stored and I do not know how to validate it.

Here is my code:

```
db.ref("/signup_emails").push({
     name: d.name,
     email: d.email
}
```

Whenever this creates an entry into the database it does so with a message_id. Like so"

```
 signup_emails { 
     - M1itOVYTq-ySh_49rH3 {
          name: "John"
          email: "example@example.com"
     }
 }
```

How do I validate that the email has only been signed up once?

Comment: There is no way to check for duplicate **values** in the Firebase Database. If you want something to be unique, you should use that as they key of the nodes under a common root. For more on this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149216/firebase-security-rules-to-check-unique-value-of-a-child-askfirebase/39151205#39151205, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243492/firebase-android-make-username-unique, and many of these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+unique+value).

Answer (score 0):

As you have things structured now, it is not possible with Firebase security rules.  If you want to know if there's child node with a specific value, and you don't know its full path, you would have to perform a query to find it.  However, security rules don't have the ability to perform a query.  You can only [reference a node by its fully specified path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#referencing_data_in_other_paths).

If you want to use security rules to find a piece of data, that data will have to be the name of a node that contains that data.  So, the email address, or some form of it, will have to be in the path, not in a value.

Or, you can push the logic into backend code that can perform the check for you.