# How to make an account number unique using Angular and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I have an account form, created by Angular Form and connected to a Firebase real-time database. In Angular, I write the following code

```
accountsForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    $key: new FormControl(null),
    accountNo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(6), Validators.minLength(6)]),  
});
```

The accountNo should be 'Required, 6 digits and Unique'. So In Angular, How can I do account No. unique?

Comment: Are you going  to pre-populate the account no or is the user going to enter it?

Comment: the user is going to enter it

Comment: So you need to verify that the number entered by the user is not already present with the Firebase via an API.

Comment: No API at all. I need to do that in client side, I don't know if Firebase can help. By the way I'm using  '@angular/fire' library

Comment: Does Firebase give you an API that you can invoke to find out all the existing account numbers? Unless you verify it in Firebase there's no way you can find out whether the number exists or not.

Comment: I don't know, I just connect myApp to firbase

Comment: You'll need to write it then OR find out if it provides some already existing API.

Comment: To make something unique in Firebase Realtime Database, you'll want to use it as the keys for nodes in a certain location. So something like `/accounts/b=nr123`, `/accounts/nr234`, as that implicitly guarantees the account numbers are unique. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328654, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39151205, and more from this list https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+realtime+database+unique+value