# How can I validate user is already signed up?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can I validate user is already signed up?

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(final GoogleSignInAccount acct, final GoogleSignInResult result) {

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

       //HOW CAN I validate user is already signup or not
                        if (Singup == true) {
                            did not create account.
                        } else {
                            create account;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //        updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

This is creating account when user already exists or not every time.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030237/firebase-check-email-registered-if-login-via-facebook-and-google You can track if a user is new or existing using Firebase Database. You would have to build that mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have an instance of `FirebaseAuth`. Then within `if (task.isSuccessful()) {...}` block, get an instance of `FirebaseUser` using `FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();`.

After which you can replace

`if (Singup == true) {
   // did not create account.
 } else {
  //   create account;
 }`

with

`if (firebaseUser == null) {
   //  did not create account.
 } else {
  //  create account;
 }`

More details can be found on [lines 137 and 197 sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L104-L122) and [here (Firebase google sigin doc)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)